# Network Card not initializing before startup programs.

Tags: networking, boot, startup, ethernet

I am using Ubuntu 12.4.  I am using this machine to display a webpage.  I have installed the MKISOK plug in for Fire Fox and set Fire Fox to open on start up.  The issue I am running into is it seems like the network card isn't initializing right away so there is a time out error.  Is there anyway to make the network card initialize first?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do that by launching a shell script at startup instead of Firefox. The shell script can pause for X seconds (to allow the network to finish loading) then launch Firefox. Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# pause for 30 seconds
sleep 30s

firefox %u
```

Make sure the shell script is executable. You can do that by checking the "Is executable" checkbox in the Properties page from your favorite file manager. Or you can use the chmod command, like this:

```
chmod +x StartFF.sh
```

Comment: If you're satisfied that your question has been answered, could you please also accept the answer so that the question is marked as 'answered'.